# Example for "so" as a subordinating conjunction

Tags: conjunctions, clauses

On a webpage called [Daily Writing Tips](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/25-subordinating-conjunctions/) there is a list of 25 subordinating conjunctions including *so*. The example they're giving is this:

> “So sure were you of your theory about them, you ignored evidence that you were wrong.”

- Isn't that an adverb here?
- Isn't the first clause in fact the main clause while the following two are dependent?

Comment: You are right, and Sally's comment in the web page you link to explains why.

Comment: @Shoe: I'm not sure how meaningful it is to identify *either* component of OP's example as the "main clause". But if we *have* to, surely it must be the statement *you ignored evidence that you were wrong*. The "explanatory" component *(because you were [**so**] cocksure)* seems far more "optional" to me.

Comment: I agree with the OP that the main clause is ‘So sure were you of your theory about them’, and that *so* is an adverb. It’s another way of saying ‘You were so sure of your theory about them’. The rest of the sentence is a post-predicate *that*-clause.

Comment: @FumbleFingers. Without the fronting of _so sure_ and with the reinsertion of the elided _that_ we get "_You were so sure of your theory about them that you ignored evidence that you were wrong_". On such a reading the first clause is indeed the main clause. You are right, however, if the sentence is rewritten: "_You ignored evidence that you were wrong because you were so sure of your theory about them._"

Comment: @Shoe: Humour me (I'm sometimes a bit slow, and I still don't get this!). What if we don't bother with the word ***because**?* Does the "main clause" of *"So confident was he, he bet the farm"* change purely because of the different word order if we switch it to *"He bet the farm, so confident was he"*?

Comment: Rewriting changes the meaning, of course. The assertion of one is the presupposition of the other, and v.v.

Comment: @FumbleFingers. It seems to me that in the first _he bet the farm_ is subordinate to _so confident was he_ (ie. the main clause). In the second, the main clause is _he bet the farm_, with his confidence being the reason (and hence subordinate). Having said that, I find _So confident was he, he bet the farm_ of somewhat dubious grammaticality.

Comment: @Shoe: I don't know how to make Google Books show me *all* such constructions (using other adjectives that might be more common), but I can't see anything particularly wrong with my example (or these other three instances of [*So confident was he he*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22So+confident+was+he+he%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)). I'm left with the impression that where two "interdependent" clauses are being juxtaposed like this, the rule of thumb seems to be *Whichever comes first must be the main clause, because we **usually** say the most important thing first*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers. I rather sidetracked the discussion with my comment about grammaticality. On topic, I think the fact that _that_ can be inserted before the second clause is a strong indication that the clause should be considered subordinate. It seems the main reason it is debatable in the present examples is due to the fronting of the complement.

Comment: @Shoe: oic. Finally I've got something *that* makes sense to me! ty.

Comment: Well, according to what I was taught, the second part is the main part, and the first part just modifies it.  'So' is an adverb modifying an adjective, which in turn doesn't really constitute a subject.  But the last part of the sentence is a straight-up proper sentence all by itself.  Even going by the feel of it, during the intro we are merely biding our time before they reveal the real info in the last part.  Too lazy to get a reference for it right now, but the books were clear on this when I was in school.

Comment: So, not a very good example of _so_ as a conjunction...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we have a typical case of an inverted result clause.If it wasn't inverted it would be written this way,"“You were so sure  of your theory about them, you ignored evidence that you were wrong.” Maybe that was what confused you.

So to answer your questions, yes, "so" here is an adverb, and  it always introduces the main clause in **result clauses**. As for the other two sentences, they are indeed dependent ones.(dependent sentences don't change in a "result clause inversion"
Example: I was so tired (that) I fell asleep immediately.
Inversion: So tired was I (that) I fell asleep immediately.

Answer (score 0):

If the words before the comma were intended to be the independent clause the writer would not have used the comma hence the reason for thinking the writer intended the words after the comma as the independent clause.

Answer (score -2):

Everything before the comma looks like its an adverbial clause that modifies the verb “ignored” . Giving the reason why ignored. Therefore “so” is a subordinate conjunction.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please consider adding references to show why you're right, and Vic's accepted answer from three years ago is wrong?